# htaccess SEF URLS dont work with the word 'drills'

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, sef

I have a strange problem where my SEF URLs just wont work for the word 'drills' I have just got around the issue by using a different word but Id like to know why this doesn't work.

This is my entire htaccess file:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^page/([0-9])/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This works perfectly and redirects **domain.com/page/1** to the correct **domain.com/index.php?page=1**

However, if I change the htaccess file to this:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^drills/([0-9])/?$ /index.php?drill=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I just get a url not found error.

To find out where it was going wrong I edited the htaccess 1 letter at a time so page became drills and it all worked correctly until I changed the initial letter. So this works:

```
   RewriteRule ^prills/([0-9])/?$ /index.php?drill=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

but this is a URL not found:

```
   RewriteRule ^drills/([0-9])/?$ /index.php?drill=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Is there something special about the word 'drills' that means I can't use it for SEF URLs?

To fix it I've just used training-drills instead but it's bugging me that I couldn't get it to work with just the word 'drills'

Comment: Is there a filesystem directory called "drills" or a file whose basename is "drills" (eg. "drills.php" etc.) `/index.php?drill=$1` - Presumably you also modified your script to look for the URL param `drill` (no `s`) as opposed to `page`?

Comment: I had created the file drills.php which was the intended destination but I had also amended the htaccess to reflect that and it didn't work. It was just a direct copy of index.php and they both had a script echoing the drill parameter. No folders called drills

Comment: "I just get a url not found error." - Is this a 404 response from Apache or is the "not found error" generated by your script (so your script is in fact called)? "I had created the file drills.php" - had you also created `prills.php` when you were testing `/prills/1`?